# AWS Amplify - JS files get downloaded in a loop

Tags: aws-amplify

In order to test multiple branchs in parallel, I started using AWS Amplify.
I successfully got it to build and deploy branches but when I go to the deployed website, two of my js files get downloaded in a loop until browser eventually crashes.

The website itself is built using angularjs 1.x

I am using the following rewrite/redirect rule (taken from AWS documentation):

Source address: `</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>`

Target address: `/index.html`

Type: `200 (Rewrite)`

I don't use any other rewrite or redirect of any kind.

I tried contacting the Amplify team on Github (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/760) but I've been ignored so far.

Is there any additional step that needs to be taken to make it work?

Thanks for your help in advance.